# How innodb_log_file_size would affect performance?

Tags: mysql, innodb

I am using MySQL-v5.5.12 and I got the same performance as MySQL-v5.5.1.39. So I decided to increase the `innodb_log_file_size`.

Please explain how the `innodb_log_file_size` would affect the performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the [MySQL performance blog](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/07/03/choosing-proper-innodb_log_file_size/) has covered this pretty well.

Comment: If your answer is going to be just a link, a comment will suffice.

Comment: Hi @Sukumar, Thanks for suggestion. I already gone through the link but optimal size not mentioned. Any optimal size for innodb_log_file_size?.

Comment: @mac, I didn't know about that. Will keep that in mind from now on.

@kumar_88, There is no specific optimal size. It will depend on a number of parameters such as the machine hardware, amount of data being stored, insert frequency etc. I would suggest choosing a profile in my.cnf that is proportional to your machine size and leave it at that. The default values usually cover a broad range and work well.

Comment: Besides being a link-only answer (strongly discouraged here), this blog post also *doesn't* have this covered well. It indicates that a higher value for this setting harms performance of crash recovery, but improves performance of... *something*. But precisely what the performance improvement is or when it applies is left unspecified.

Answer (score -2):

[CalculatingInnoDBLogFileSize - RuleofThumb](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2008/11/21/how-to-calculate-a-good-innodb-log-file-size/)

Comment: Link-only answers are considered very low quality. Please clarify, explain, and elaborate on your answers.